# ATM machine example in PHP

Tags: php, division, reminders

I need to write a PHP script that calculates the No. of time it divides a number and reminder too. Lets say `$amount=9200;` if I divide this with **5000** then output should be `5000: 1 times` and `Reminder: 4200`. I think i need to use `$n=$amount%5000;` But I got only reeminder not the no. of times it divides.

Thanks!!

Comment: For "ATM machine", see http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=redundant%20acronym

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well-known as the euclidean division :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

```
$amount = 9200;
$divide = 5000;
$times = floor($amount/$divide);
$reminder = $amount%$divide;

echo "$amount = $times times $divide plus $reminder";
```

Comment: He already has the remainder. He wants the times. `floor()` is more than capable here.

Comment: @BenM - actually, `floor()` returns a `float` value and dividing+flooring is more expensive in terms of processing than the multiplication option (ie `$divide * $times`). You need two operations either way to get the full answer; you may as well use the one that performs better.

Answer (score 0):

The `%` operator will give you the remainder and then you will need to do another operation to get the number of times that you divided.

```
$times = floor($amount/5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$times = floor($amount / 5000);
$remainder = $amount % 5000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

class  ATM
{
    public function deliver( $note )
    {
        // code to grab that not from the cash boxes...
    }
}

$notes = new SplFixedArray(5);
$notes[0] = 100;
$notes[1] = 50;
$notes[2] = 20;
$notes[3] = 10;
$notes[4] = 5;

$notesKey = 0;

$withdraw = 920;
$allocated = 0;

$deliver = new SplQueue();

// work out biggest notes for remaining value and queue
while($allocated < $withdraw)
{
    $remains  = ($withdraw-$allocated) % $notes[$notesKey];
    $numNotes = (($withdraw-$allocated)-$remains)/$notes[$notesKey];
    for( $i = 0; $i < $numNotes; $i++ )
    {
        $allocated += $notes[$notesKey];
        $deliver->enqueue($notesKey);
    }
    ++$notesKey;
}

$atm = new ATM();
while(!$deliver->isempty())
{
     $atm->deliver($notes[$deliver->dequeue()]);
}
?>
```

Something like that should do the trick...